# PrimeNg grid system is not working as per the documentation

Tags: angular, primeng, nrwl-nx

I am using PrimeNG in my application and have installed all the required dependencies as per the official documentation. I am trying the example of the grid system available on their website and it's not working.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="p-grid">
    <div class="p-col">1</div>
    <div class="p-col">2</div>
    <div class="p-col">3</div>
</div>
```

Here are styles in my angular.json file

```
"styles": [
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "./node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
          "./node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova/theme.css",
          "./node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
          "./node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.css",
          "apps/customer-application/src/styles.scss"
        ]
```

It's printing all these three lines vertically (in a single column) but, as per the documentation it should print it in a single line i.e, horizontally (in 3 different columns). I am using Angular 12+ and running my app over Nx CLI. Any help would be appreciated!Thanks

Comment: What version of primeflex are you using? They removed the `p-` prefix for classes in the most recent version.

Comment: thank you so much. It resolved my issue!

Comment: Why didn't they change the documentation on their site?

Comment: https://www.primefaces.org/primeflex/migration. Not sure when will update all the rest of the docs. I had to deal with this over the weekend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They removed the `p-` prefix for `primeflex` classes in the most recent version (3.x).

See [here](https://www.primefaces.org/primeflex/migration) for the migration path.

See [here](https://www.primefaces.org/primeflex) for the latest docs.